# Indexing redundantly named vector in R

Tags: r

In R, when having a redundantly named vector, why is it not possible to retrieve all elements in the named vector with the selection operator?

```
v <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
names(v) <- c("a","b","c","c","a")
v["c"] ## Returns only 3, not c(3,4)
```

It looks like R assumes that vector names are unique and only retrieves the first element in a vector whose name match the argument in the selection operator.

Is this some kind of optimization? Would it not be beneficial if we were able to select multiple elements in a vector with the same name attribute?
Is the point to guarantee that the number of elements returned when using the indexing operator is the same as the number of elements in the indexing vector?

Comment: Why would you want to have a list with non-unique names?

Comment: Not directly related, but knowing about the [make.names](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/make.names.html) function is often handy for removing redundant names without too much user interference

Comment: My intention was to use the vector as a lookup, to translate from e.g. genesymbolIDs to entrezdatabaseIDs. In this case, several genesymbolIDs in names(v) can possibly map to the same entrezdatabaseID in v, giving redundancy in names(v).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use names for what you're trying to do.  You're making a categorical variable, not naming each item uniquely.  This is an important semantic distinction.

```
v <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
cat_v <- c("a","b","c","c","a")
v[cat_v == 'c'] ## Returns c(3,4)
```

Comment: OK thanks. I guess that the intention of R is that names should be unique, at least when using [

Answer (score 3):

This is an educated guess, so confirmation or disproval is welcome. (confirmation below)

From `?"["`: "Character vectors will be matched to the names of the object".

```
> match("c",names(v))
[1] 3
```

You could get around this by using:

```
> v[names(v)%in%"c"]
c c 
3 4
```

**EDIT**: `[` is a Primitive function, so it isn't actually using `match`. The source code holds the answer, but I haven't found it yet.

**EDIT2:**

The answer from the source code: The R function `[` calls the C function `do_subset`, which can be found in the source file **./src/main/subset.c**. In the example you gave, the C function `stringSubscript` eventually gets called, and this iterates over each name of the vector being subset (`v` in this case) until it finds a match. At that point, the iteration is stopped and the corresponding index and name are returned.

Therefore, only the value of your vector corresponding to the first matching name is returned when you subset using `v["a"]`. And it is therefore recommended to follow the suggestions in the other answer and the comments to use unique names :)